# Getting an exception error when trying to run the default Program.cs (C#) in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I'm taking a course to learn C#. The course had me create a number of directories from the Command Line Interface (CLI). When I tested the directories I created in the CLI (on the top-level folder), by typing the command "dotnet run", it ran the default code correctly, returning "Hello World!"

I then moved on to open the top-level folder in Visual Studio 2019 so I could begin editing. The folder opened correctly and all of my directories were in the Solution Explorer. However, when I attempted to run the default code, I got the following exception.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in Unknown Module.
>   Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on? The strange thing is when I create a new C# project and attempt to run the code, it runs fine. It just seems to be this particular project that's giving me an issue. I deleted the directories and started over from scratch, following the tutorial step by step, but got the same exception.

I should also note that when I created the .NET file (i.e. "dotnet new") in the CLI, I created a Console Application. I created the top-level directory of "testproject". I created two directories inside of testproject: "src" and "test". Inside of the "src" directory, I created the directory "TestProject" and then inside of TestProject, I typed the command "dotnet new console". When I changed directory (cd) to "testproject" (top level), and typed the command "dotnet run" it returned "Hello World!" However, as mentioned, when I opened the top-level testproject folder in Visual Studio, and tried running, it went into break mode and threw that exception.

This noob appreciates the help!

**Visual Studio version information (the application is up to date):**

> Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.5.4
>   VisualStudio.16.Release/16.5.4+30011.22 Microsoft .NET Framework
>   Version 4.8.03752
>
> Installed Version: Community
>
> ASP.NET and Web Tools 2019   16.5.236.49856 ASP.NET and Web Tools 2019
>
> ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2019   16.5.236.49856 For additional
>   information, visit https://www.asp.net/
>
> Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   16.5.236.49856 Azure App Service
>   Tools v3.0.0
>
> Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools   16.5.236.49856 Azure Functions
>   and Web Jobs Tools
>
> C# Tools
>   3.5.0-beta4-20153-05+20b9af913f1b8ce0a62f72bea9e75e4aa3cf6b0e C# components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and
>   settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.
>
> Common Azure Tools   1.10 Provides common services for use by Azure
>   Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.
>
> IntelliCode Extension   1.0 IntelliCode Visual Studio Extension
>   Detailed Info
>
> Microsoft Azure Tools   2.9 Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 2019 - v2.9.30207.1
>
> Microsoft Continuous Delivery Tools for Visual Studio   0.4
>   Simplifying the configuration of Azure DevOps pipelines from within
>   the Visual Studio IDE.
>
> Microsoft JVM Debugger   1.0 Provides support for connecting the
>   Visual Studio debugger to JDWP compatible Java Virtual Machines
>
> Microsoft Library Manager   2.1.25+gdacdb9b7a1 Install client-side
>   libraries easily to any web project
>
> Microsoft MI-Based Debugger   1.0 Provides support for connecting
>   Visual Studio to MI compatible debuggers
>
> Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Containers   1.1 Develop, run,
>   validate your ASP.NET Core applications in the target environment. F5
>   your application directly into a container with debugging, or CTRL +
>   F5 to edit & refresh your app without having to rebuild the container.
>
> NuGet Package Manager   5.5.0 NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio.
>   For more information about NuGet, visit https://docs.nuget.org/
>
> ProjectServicesPackage Extension   1.0 ProjectServicesPackage Visual
>   Studio Extension Detailed Info
>
> SQL Server Data Tools   16.0.62003.05170 Microsoft SQL Server Data
>   Tools
>
> SQL Server Reporting Services   15.0.19103.0 Microsoft SQL Server
>   Reporting Services Designers  Version 15.0.19103.0
>
> TypeScript Tools   16.0.20225.2001 TypeScript Tools for Microsoft
>   Visual Studio
>
> Visual Basic Tools
>   3.5.0-beta4-20153-05+20b9af913f1b8ce0a62f72bea9e75e4aa3cf6b0e Visual Basic components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and
>   settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.
>
> Visual F# Tools 10.8.0.0 for F# 4.7
>   16.5.0-beta.20181.6+85af456066acd4e76d2bc7821b44a325e46f2fca Microsoft Visual F# Tools 10.8.0.0 for F# 4.7
>
> Visual Studio Code Debug Adapter Host Package   1.0 Interop layer for
>   hosting Visual Studio Code debug adapters in Visual Studio
>
> Visual Studio Container Tools Extensions (Preview)   1.0 View, manage,
>   and diagnose containers within Visual Studio.
>
> Visual Studio Tools for Containers   1.0 Visual Studio Tools for
>   Containers

Comment: I followed your instructions and couldn't compile with "dotnet run" from the toplevel directory, although I could compile it with "dotnet run --project src\TestProject".

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right. That's how I initially compiled it. When I said "moved on to open the top-level folder in Visual Studio", I meant I launched Visual Studio, selected "open local folder" then navigated to the "testproject" folder (directory) I created. It opened fine, I have "src" and "test" in the Solution Explorer. However, when I try to run Program.cs, I get the exception every time. I should also note, I initially tried creating just a basic C# project and I was able to run it successfully in Visual Studio (the CLI opened, displaying "Hello World!").

Comment: Error is probably due reason you deleted a file from directory manually but have entry in project file, which is throwing error  `FileNotFoundException`. If this is case edit project file & remove that file or look if some file is showing with yellow triangle icon in solution explorer. Add that file or remove it.

Comment: Interesting, I'm pretty sure I didn't manually delete anything. I should have mentioned that the person who created the tutorial appears to be using a different version of Visual Studio (it looks like a more basic version with an "Editor" instead of a Solution Explorer and the Visual Studio icon is blue). Not sure if this is related. I expanded all the folders in the Solution Explorer and nothing's yellow. I think I'm going to try creating the directories from scratch again and just changing the name of the root directory slightly.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create the project from within Visual Studio? File -> New -> Project.

Does a project file get created in the testproject/src/TestProject/ directory. It will be called TestProject.csproj. Open this in Visual Studio (File -> Open -> Project/Solution) and use this as your root directory. I wouldn't worry about trying to layout custom directories in Visual Studio for now since your a noob like you say.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing: just creating a new project. And yes, there's a project in there. And when I open the project/solution, it runs fine. I was just worried about the directories since the course is using them. Can I simply create folders in the File Explorer and arrange them accordingly to compensate for the directory issue I'm having when they're created in the CLI?

Comment: If you are going to use visual studio you need to add folders from within it by right clicking on your project name and clicking Add -> New Folder. you can either work using a command lne or visual studio but trying to mix the two could cause you problems. Your project root folder in VS will be whatever folder contains the project file

Comment: Visual studio will also want to save a solution file (*.sln) which can be saved anywhere